# Oracle CONCAT from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

```
UPDATE table1 t1 
SET t1.value_1 = CONCAT(t2.value_2,t1.value_1) 
WHERE t1.id = t2.t1_id AND t1.id = '0123';
```

Can anyone help with how I do something like the above query?
Basically I need to take the value in table 1 and prefix a value from table 2 to it.   Everything seems fine except the obvious issue, of the query not knowing what t2 is.

Comment: In other words, you are asking for the multiple-table update syntax, aren't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
update  ( select t1.value_1, t2.value_2 
          from table1 t1, table2 t2 
          where t2.id = t1.id 
            and t1.id = '0123' )
set value_1 = value_1 || value_2
```

you will need to ensure that table2 has a unique id key constraint or it won't work.

Comment: Yep, pretty much something like this (my SQL: UPDATE table1 t1 SET t1.t1value = CONCAT((SELECT CONCAT(t2.t2value,' ') FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.t2id = t1.t1id), t1.t1value) WHERE t1.t1id = 'XYX';
)